# Writing a BufferedImage cache and save it to disk

Tags: java, caching, serialization, bufferedimage

I'm developing a `java` application in which I load some long lists containing images (downloaded from web), so I added a quick `HashMap<String,BufferedImage>` as a cache, to avoid redownloading the same image multiple times.

This works fine and the application is way faster, but it would be nice to let this cache persist through the various sessions, so I changed my cache to be serialized.

`BufferedImage` is not `Serializable`, so I had to wrote my custom methods.

My file structure should be something like:

- (int) number of elements
- [(URL) image's key
- (Object) image written using ImageIO] n times

While file saving seems fine (at least I have no exceptions), when I try to load the `URL` it throws `java.io.OptionalDataException` with `length = 4` and I don't understand why. The first iteration goes fine, but I have this exception as soon as I try to load the second `URL`, so I suspect that there's something wrong in the way I load the first image.

Here's the full code :

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class PicturesCache {

    private static HashMap<String, BufferedImage> picturesCache;

    private static final String cacheDiskLocation = "pictures_cache.map";

    private static void writeCache(ObjectOutputStream oos, HashMap<String, BufferedImage> data) throws IOException {
        // Number of saved elements
        oos.writeInt(data.size());
        // Let's write (url, image) for each entry in the cache
        for (Entry<String, BufferedImage> entry : data.entrySet()) {   
            oos.writeObject(new URL(entry.getKey()));
            ImageIO.write(entry.getValue(), "png", oos);
        }
    }

    private static HashMap<String, BufferedImage> readCache(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Number of saved elements
        int size = ois.readInt();
        // Cache
        HashMap<String, BufferedImage> result = new HashMap<>(size);
        // Let's read (url, image) and add them to cache
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String url = ((URL) ois.readObject()).toString(); // EXCEPTION HERE
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ois);            
            result.put(url, image);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void loadCache() {
        picturesCache = new HashMap<>();
        File file = new File(cacheDiskLocation);
        if (file.isFile()) {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                picturesCache = readCache(ois);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PicturesCache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    ois.close();
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PicturesCache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Cache loaded with " + picturesCache.size() + " elements");
    }

    public static void saveCache() {
        File file = new File(cacheDiskLocation);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            file.createNewFile();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            writeCache(oos, picturesCache);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PicturesCache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                System.out.println("Cache saved with " + picturesCache.size() + " elements");
                oos.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PicturesCache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean contains(String url) {
        return picturesCache.containsKey(url);
    }

    public static BufferedImage get(String url) {
        return picturesCache.get(url);
    }

    public static void put(String url, BufferedImage image) {
        picturesCache.put(url, image);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `ImageIO.read(...)` doesn't read all the data that was written using `ImageIO.write(...)`. You can write the image to the `ObjectOutputStread` as a `byte[]`. For example:

```
private static void writeCache(ObjectOutputStream oos,
        HashMap<String, BufferedImage> data) throws IOException {
    // Number of saved elements
    oos.writeInt(data.size());
    // Let's write (url, image) for each entry in the cache
    for (Entry<String, BufferedImage> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        oos.writeObject(new URL(entry.getKey()));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(entry.getValue(), "jpg", baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        oos.writeObject(bytes);
    }
}

private static HashMap<String, BufferedImage> readCache(
        ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Number of saved elements
    int size = ois.readInt();
    // Cache
    HashMap<String, BufferedImage> result = new HashMap<>(size);
    // Let's read (url, image) and add them to cache
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String url = ((URL) ois.readObject()).toString(); // EXCEPTION HERE
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                (byte[]) ois.readObject());
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bais);
        result.put(url, image);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can't try it now but I suspected that this was the issue because of the number shown in the exception. Do you know why `ImageIO.read(...)` has this strange behavior?

Comment: @StepTNT I'm not sure, it could be because the `ImageReader` used to read the image is not using the same format as the `ImageWriter` or because the `write(...)` method adds some metadata which is not consumed by the `read(...)` method.

Comment: @StepTNT , On my system the error doesn't occur if I use `jpg` instead of `png` (`ImageIO.write(entry.getValue(), "jpg", oos);`) so I guess the problem is that `ImageWriter` and `ImageReader` use different formats.

Comment: Well, that's odd since I copied that code from an answer here on SO and it used `png`. I just changed your code to work with `png` and it's fine here, thanks for your help.